# PHP+JQuery+AJAX Form not getting resubmitted with different values

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

This is embarrassing but I cant seem to figure out why my form wont repost after changing the values.

To be clearer, I have this password recovery form in which user enters the email address. The form is processed in PHP through AJAX and a validation/success message is displayed on the form page.

The issue here is that if the user has entered an invalid email address, it displays the error message but if the user then corrects the email address and tries to submit again, it doesn't process the input unless if the page is explicitly refreshed (in which case it shows the resubmission warning which is very annoying). Is there some property that sets the form and needs to be 'un-set' through code? How can I improve this experience? I have posted the code below.

```
<form id="pwd_rec_form" method="post" action="">
          <div class="row">
              <div  class="large-6 columns">
                  <input type="email" required placeholder="Email ID" name="email"/>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div id="val_msg" class="row"></div>
          <div class="row">
              <div  class="large-6 columns">
                  <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send" class="button"/>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div  class="large-6 columns">
                  <a href="index.php">Back to login page</a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </form>

<script>
     $(function()
     {
        $("#pwd_rec_form").submit(function()
        {
          var formdata = $(this).serializeArray();

          var hideMsg = function() {$("#val_msg").hide()};

          //alert (dataString);return false;
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "recover-password.php",
            data: formdata,
            success: function(res)
            {
              $('#val_msg').html(res);
              setTimeout(hideMsg, 5000);
            }
          });

          $("#pwd_rec_form").trigger("reset");
          return false;
        });
     });
</script>
```

PHP :

```
<?php
  include 'db-connect.php';

  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
  {
$conn = getDBConnection();

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo('  <div data-alert class="alert-box secondary">' . mysqli_connect_error() . '
            </div>'
        );
    exit();
}

$eID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim(strip_tags($_POST['email'])));

$query = 'SELECT password FROM member_login WHERE email_id = "' . $eID . '";';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($result == FALSE)
{
    echo('  <div data-alert class="alert-box secondary">' . mysqli_error($conn) . '
            </div>'
        );
}
else
{
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) // User not found.
  {
      echo('<small class="error">This email address is not registered with us.</small>');
  }
  else
  {
    $pswd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    //mail the pswd

    echo('  <div data-alert class="alert-box success">
                Your password has been successfully sent to your registered email address.
            </div>'
        );

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have a submit button, which automatically submits the form and refreshes the page, so your javascript doesn't get used. Try making your submit button a `type="button"` and then changing your jQuery to `$("#pwd_rec_form").click(function()` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook the form submit, or if you wanted you can hook the click event of the submit button, prevent the default action and instead do your javascript code. Here is an example hooking the "submit_button" click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#submit_button").click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             // Do your ajax stuff
      });
});
```

Alternative you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(form).submit(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             // Do your ajax stuff
      });
});
```

The code above just hooks the form on the submit request, prevents the default action, and then you slap your ajax code in there.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your help guys. I knew it was something silly. Turns out the form was getting processed but the validation/success messages were not being displayed as the div element that I was hiding using javascript during the first submission needed to be shown again for the second attempt!

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pwd_rec_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // insert AJAX call
});
```

It worked for me, the event is trigged on each click.

Best regards,